Widgets alignments inside column
Let's imagine that there is a container with a column. It has a row and a container.
I want the row to be centered horizontally and the container to be pressed to the left edge relative to the row.
If I give an example, let's imagine that the container width is 126
row takes up 100, which means if we center, then the "margin" on the left and right is 13 and the container should have 13 on the left
I hope I explained what I'm trying to get.
Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English
Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [Text('Center'),Text('Row')],
            ),
            Container(child: Text('Container'),)
          ],
        ),
      )

I tried using a LayoutBuilder, but it seems to me that this is not the right approach and it is better not to take it into account.
I also tried to specify alignment for the container, but it is logical that it will be set according to the parent container.
Example in the picture at the request in the comments

not quite clear, could you restate your question.

@A-E I tried to convey the essence of the question as accurately as possible, I probably couldn't do it better. Either because of my intelligence or because of my knowledge of the language)

The main point is that the Row is centered and the container under it moves to the left at the same distance as the Row
Since the content in the Row may differ in width
I don’t even know how to say it more simply and accurately)

@muri_top what do you expected actually?

@NipulRathod Rathod  My main goal is for the Row to be centered and the container below to be left aligned with the same "margin" as the Row.

It's still confusing. Can you share image what you expecting?

@muri_top Have you tried giving the container a fixed width?

I've added code that aligns with what you were aiming for. Hope it helps.

Question is not very clear but from what I am able to get, try below.
For the column give property of
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch
and Wrap the Column with a parent widget IntrinsicWidth.

Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem
I changed the description and added a picture as an example, maybe it will help
I found a rather stupid solution for myself
The width of the container is fixed for me, as is the approximate number of characters in 1 container
Which helps me calculate the width occupied by black text and calculate the indent for gray text (from the picture)
But the task seems simple but interesting, and perhaps the answer will be useful to someone

So, in your white background container, add Row with a constant SizedBox having required width and Column as two children. For Column set mainAxisAlignment as start and the children could be your required Texts

Try below code...
Container(
  width: 126,
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Text("text"),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text("Center"),
          Text("Row"),
        ],
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: Container(
          child: Text("Container"),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)

